# Laravel 6 - new way of displaying validation messages

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-blade, laravel-6

When I used Laravel 5.6 I displayed validation errors in blade that way:

```
@if(session()->has('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {!! session()->get('error') !!}
    </div>
@endif
```

In Laravel 6 it does not work. Do you know how to do it in correct way?

My validation:

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users'
        ], [], []);
```

Take a look - I do not want to display message that way:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

I want to have one `notifications.blade.php` file where I display all errors. That is why I need implementation of `session()->has('error')`

That solution is not solving problem...

```
@if ($errors->has('username'))
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
<input type="text" name="username">
```

Comment: What is the way you think to display errors? Please explain in more .

Comment: Look, it is at the beginning of question.

Comment: So `session()->has('error')` not working in laravel 6 right?

Comment: yest that is that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display validation errors per input name

```
@if ($errors->has('username'))
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
<input type="text" name="username">
```

Comment: It is not the solution because I want to have one notifications.blade.php file where I display all errors. That is why I need implementation of session()->has('error')

Comment: How do you pass this error to your view? `$errors` is the result of failed validation and must always be looped over. `session()->get('error')` is a single string that is added manually to your redirect or view.

Comment: In old way I did it as at the beginning of my question

Comment: I want to display it like this: {!! session()->get('error') !!}

Comment: Yes, but how does it look in your controller?

Comment: You rather ask how validation works - I updated question

Comment: what does session()->get('error') contain when you have more than 1 validation error? What is the output of your view in 5.6?

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code snippets:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" value="">
 @if ($errors->has('name'))
 <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
 @endif
```

In the same way, we can show validation messages on other forms of fields.

Comment: It is not the solution because I want to have one notifications.blade.php file where I display all errors. That is why I need implementation of session()->has('error')